# How do I get the current pthread ID?

Tags: macos, pthreads

In system.log, I can see for my process:

```
thread 515376 caught burning CPU! It used more than 50% CPU
```

I use multiple threads so I've tried printing the thread ID in the runnable method that the thread uses like:

```c
void* runnable1(void* ptr)
{
    pthread_t tid = pthread_self();
    printf("HELLO from thread runnable1 with id : %ld\n", tid);

    ...
}
```

However, I get an ID like:

```
HELLO from thread runnable1 with id : 4488212480
```

which is very different than the one from system.log.

The question is how do I get the thread ID the way it appears in system.log?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Try:

```c
uint64_t tid;
pthread_threadid_np(NULL, &tid);
printf("HELLO from thread runnable1 with id : %ld\n", tid);
```

Comment: It's worth adding that there exists another `_np` function that gives an integer for a `pthread_t`: `mach_port_t pthread_mach_thread_np(pthread_t)`. This value may be relevant for some kernel-related debugging.